# string type in python language

Tags: python, string

as I learn in my college in programming  concept language course
the string length in any language may be one of three:

1. Static: as COBOL, Java’s String class
2. Limited Dynamic Length:as C and C++
   In these languages, a special character is used to indicate the end of a string’s characters, rather than maintaining the length
3. Dynamic (no maximum): SNOBOL4, Perl, JavaScript

What of these options python string length are?

Comment: Java String length is static? That's something new.

Comment: @Tom I think he is referring to the fact that java strings are immutable

Comment: I think you mean constant, not `static`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html read this

Comment: Javascript strings are also immutable, though.

Comment: static length mean : compile-time descriptor

Comment: ?? I can ask for user input and then make an array of the user inputs size in java.

Comment: Java string lengths aren't fixed at compile time.

Comment: as I understand from my teacher about static : for example if I declare String x="ABC" it have length of 3 this length cannot change at run time :/ but what about python can it change ???

Comment: Aren't C strings static? Only because they are not length prefixed doesn't mean they could dynamically change the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python strings are *immutable*.  Any operation that appears to be changing a string's length is actually returning a new string.

Definately not your third option -- a string can start out arbitrary long but can't later change it's length.  Your option 1 sounds closest.

You may find [the Strings subsection of this web page](http://rigaux.org/language-study/various/mutability-and-sharing/) helpful.  Even in a language where strings can, in general, change length, that may not be true of all strings, depending on where they originate (e.g. code text) or how they are declared.